# How to add only numerical values to text boxes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, validation

I have made a vb.net form that has 3 text boxes and a button called Calculate. All I want to do is enter some values to the textboxes and click the button which calculates the numbers. I have done the calculation coding part.

Now I want to enter only numbers to the textboxes and if I enter alphabetics or symbols I need to get an critical error message with ok button when I click the ok button.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Int32.TryParse` (or `Double.TryParse`) to check if the entered number is an integer (or double, with decimal places).

```
Dim num As Int32
If Not Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, num) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter only integers!", "Critical Warning",
                     MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
End If
```

[**`MessageBox.Show` Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/365dky5y.aspx)

Comment: Tim is there any way to get that display if i keep one or more text boxes empty???

Comment: @Sajith: I don't understand. The code above would show the MessageBox also when the user enters nothing since `""` is not convertible to a number.

Comment: another thing @Tim, How can i apply this code for all three textboxes???

Comment: @Sajith: Simply replace `textBox1` with the name of your textboxes. Since you have threee textboxes you have to use three `If` statements.

Comment: Thank you very much Tim. I got my answer......

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to be able to handle this as the user is entering their values in a WinForm app, this works quite well:

```
Private Sub TextBox_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Textbox.KeyDown
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.D0 To Keys.D9, Keys.NumPad0 To Keys.NumPad9, _
                    Keys.OemPeriod, Keys.Decimal, Keys.Back, Keys.Delete, _
                    Keys.Left, Keys.Right
                If e.Shift = True Then
                    e.SuppressKeyPress = True
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                e.SuppressKeyPress = False
            Case Else
                e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        End Select
    End Sub
```

It allows for numbers, decimals and navigation within the textbox (delete, backspace, left & right).

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify if you are coding for Asp or for WinForms
WinForms:

```
Private Sub TextBoxes_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged,TextBox2.TextChanged,TextBox3.TextChanged
  'Assuming TextBox1,TextBox2,TextBox3 are your textboxes
   Dim txt as new textbox
   txt=DirectCast(sender,TextBox)
   If IsNumeric(txt.text)=False Then
     'Here put your code: what you would to do if user insert a not numeric value
     'For example, messagobox, ErrorProvider, or clear the textBox etc
   End if

End Sub
```

Comment: `IsNumeric` is an old VB6 function which is provided in VB.NET for backwards compatibility, but in new code, it's best to use the new .NET methods such as `TryParse`.  Also, unless you really need the strictness of `DirectCast`, I would recommend using `CType` in most cases.

Comment: @StevenDoggart: Agree with `IsNumeric` but i always use `DirectCast` unless i need the "magic" of `CType`. It's always better to know which types are involved instead of trusting `CType` to do the work for me somehow. That prevents nasty errors and is also more consistent with C#.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I used to feel that way because I thought `DirectCast` was the closest equivalent to casting in other languages, such as C#.  However, I then realized that `DirectCast` does not use any `CType` operator overloads, so there is no way to overload the `DirectCast` operation.  So, as much as I don't like some of the additional "magic" that goes on, I feel like `CType` is a closer equivalent to standard casting.

Comment: @StevenDoggart But in that example, since we know that sender will be always a textbox , isn't preferable to use DirectCast (is also faster) ? I am asking because I want to understand better the differences between DirectCast and CType.

Comment: Yes, `DirectCast` is slightly more efficient.  I'd say if you don't understand the differences between the two, use `CType`. If you do understand the differences, only use `DirectCast` when it's exactly what you want to do and use `CType` when you don't mind if the operation is overloaded.  Otherwise, if, in the future, you ever decide to overload the operation, you may find yourself needing to fix a bunch of places that used `DirectCast` instead of `CType`.